# Get width and Height from URI of picture

Tags: android, image, width, uri

I am trying to get the widht and the Height of a picture to then be able to load it into a canvas on my activity. When I try to print this Height and Width I always get 0. I do not understand why ?

Here is my code:

```
    private void openPicture() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        try {
            InputStream stream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            int width = options.outWidth;
            int height = options.outHeight;
            Log.d("DEBUG", ""+ width);
            loadPicture(width, height);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("FingerPainterView", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void loadPicture(int w, int h) {

        try {
            // attempt to load the uri provided, scale to fit our canvas
            InputStream stream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            bitmap  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, Math.max(w, h), Math.max(w, h), false);
            stream.close();
            bm.recycle();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("FingerPainterView", e.toString());
        }
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
private void getImageWidthAndHeight(Uri uri){
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
   int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
   int imageWidth = options.outWidth;

}
```